# Big O in proof for corollary of Chebyshev's Theorem

Tags: number-theory, logarithms, asymptotics

I am trying to understand the proof for $c_1*n*\log{n} \leq p_n \leq c_2*n*\log{n}$ where $c_1, c_2$ are constants and $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime.
I understand the proof for the lower bound, however I am struggling with a step in the proof for the upper bound.
You first use Chebyshev's Theorem: $\exists a,b$, constants, s.t. $a\frac{x}{\log{x}}\leq \pi(x) \leq b\frac{x}{\log{x}}$, where $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function.
Setting $x = p_n$ and taking logs gives: $\log{n}+\log{\log{p_n}} \geq \log{a}+\log{p_n}$ (1).
So far I understand everything. The step I don't understand is that from the above equation it is inferred that $\log{p_n} = O(\log{n})$ (2). I understand the definition of the Big O notation, but just can't see how (1) can be manipulated to show (2). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of conintuity of the exponential function $\frac{\operatorname{log}(\operatorname{log}(p_n))}{\operatorname{log}(p_n)} \rightarrow 0$ if and only if $\operatorname{exp}(\frac{\operatorname{log}(\operatorname{log}(p_n)}{\operatorname{log}(p_n)})) = \operatorname{log(p_n)}^{\frac{1}{\operatorname{log}(p_n)}} \rightarrow 1$, which is true since $\sqrt[x]{x} \rightarrow 1$ for $x \rightarrow \infty$ and $\sqrt[x]{x}$ is continuous on the relevant domain.

Manipulating $(2)$ gives $\frac{\operatorname{log}(n)}{\operatorname{log}(p_n)} + \frac{\operatorname{log}(\operatorname{log}(p_n))}{\operatorname{log}(p_n)} - \frac{\operatorname{log}(a)}{\operatorname{log}(p_n)} \geq 1$. Since $\frac{\operatorname{log}(\operatorname{log}(p_n))}{\operatorname{log}(p_n)} - \frac{\operatorname{log}(a)}{\operatorname{log}(p_n)} \rightarrow 0$ and $\frac{\operatorname{log}(n)}{\operatorname{log}(p_n)} \leq 1,$ we must have $\frac{\operatorname{log}(n)}{\operatorname{log}(p_n)} \rightarrow 1$. Therefore $\frac{\operatorname{log}(n)}{\operatorname{log}(p_n)} = O(1)$ which means $\operatorname{log}(p_n) = O(\operatorname{log}(n))$.

Comment: Thank you so much. This really helped me.

Comment: @JohnStevenson Assuming $\pi(x) \in [a \frac{x}{\log x},b \frac{x}{\log x}]$, then $p_n > c n \log n \implies \pi(p_n) > \pi(c n \log n) > a \frac{c n \log n}{\log(c n \log n)}=a \frac{c n \log n}{\log n+\log c+\log \log n} > ac n-1$. Thus we have a contradiction if $c \ge  \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{n}$.
The lower bound is obtained the same way.